# Function problem with iterators and conditions

Tags: c++, sorting

I need to check if every element in list are not divideable by either on of my input and if condition is true to set that number to -1.
Problem apparently is somewhere in function.
Function test one of my input and when condition is true it switch to another condition but I need to check whole list with one input and then with another

```cpp
 #include <vector>
 #include <list>
 #include <functional>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 void find_any_default(list < int > & lista, const vector < function < bool(int) >> & funkcije, int def = -1) 
 {
    auto beginl = lista.begin(), endli = lista.end();
    int brojac = 0;
    auto beginv = funkcije.begin(), endv = funkcije.end();
    
    while (beginl != endli) 
    {
       while (beginv != endv) 
       {
          auto g = * beginv;
          
          if ((g( * beginl))) 
          {
             * beginl = -1;
          }
          break;
          ++beginv;
       }
       ++beginl;
    }
 }

 int main() 
 {
    vector < function < bool(int) >> funkcije;
    list < int > lista { 3, 4, 8, 10, 7 };
    int input;
    
    while (cin >> input) 
    {
       auto l = [input](int a) 
       {
          if ((a % input) == 0) 
          {
            return false;
          } 
          else
          {
            return true;
          }
       };
       funkcije.push_back(l);
    }
    
    find_any_default(lista, funkcije);
    
    for (auto i: lista)
    {
       std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: One problem is that your `break` statement is misplaced.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why using those ugly iterators and whiles? just do two for's and one if and you're ready. Also, I don't like to do:

```
if(x == 'something') 
  return true;
else 
  return false;
```

I prefer to just write:

```
return x == 'something';
```

I don't know if it's working or even if it's compiling, but my version of this done very fast will be something like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void find_any_default(list<int>& lista, const vector<function<bool(int)>>& funkcije, int def = -1) 
{
  for(auto& val : lista)
  {
    for(auto& fn : funkcije)
    {
      if(fn(val))
      {
        val = def;
        break; // we found one, exit second for - I doubt you need this break here.
      } 
    }
  }
}

int main() 
{
  vector<function<bool(int)>> funkcije;
  list<int> lista { 3, 4, 8, 10, 7 };
  int input;
  while (cin >> input) 
  {
    funkcije.emplace_back(
      [input](int a){ return (a % input) == 0; });
  }

  find_any_default(lista, funkcije);
  for (auto i: lista)
  {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```